# LPAD is not working in progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-db

I am tring to use lpad in `progress` `Db` but its not working.. 
Code:

```
lpad(act_num, 7, '#')
```

This code not working , Do we have any alternative way to achieve o/p. 
If act_num is 101 then o/P shoud br 7777101.

Comment: Version? LPAD seems to work in later releases at least https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf%2Flpad.html%23

Comment: Are you trying this with ABL client or SQL client?

Comment: There is an LPAD() for SQL but not for the 4gl.  Perhaps if you showed a more complete code snippet we might be able to say more about why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no lpad() function in OpenEdge, but you may be able to use the FILL() function. It takes two inputs: a character string to use as the fill value, and the number of times to repeat the string.

This will add four "7"s to the beginning of act_num, as you described in your question:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE act_num AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO INITIAL "101".

act_num = FILL("7", 4) + act_num.

MESSAGE act_num VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

The fill value can be any string, and not just a single character.